# Can an imported dataframe be converted to a function?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a simple question, but up to now I could not find a generic solution for this: 
 Let's say I have a dataframe `>df` that I got from a .csv file

```
    > df <- read.csv("foo.csv")    
    > df
      a b 
    1 1 D 
    2 2 E 
    3 3 F
```

I want to save this dataframe in a .R file to source it later again, but without reading the .csv file. It should be inside the source file, so the file can be shared with other users. 
Is there a possibility to convert this dataframe in a written function, like 
 `df<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c("D","E","F"))`

Comment: You can save the objects in the environment with  `save` or `save.image` as a .RData and then `load`

Comment: Another way is to copy and paste the output of `dput(df)` into source file if the df is not too large.

Comment: Try `dump("mtcars")` and check the generated file named "dumpdata.R".  This is works same as `dput`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `save` or `save.image` at the end of the session as a `.RData`

```
save.image("yourfile.RData")
```

and then load it when necessary so that all the objects created earlier will be loaded

```
load("yourfile.RData")
```

If we need to `save` only individual objects, just name the objects and file

```
save(df, file = "yourfile.RData")
load("yourfile.RData")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to do this:

```
mydf <- function(){
  data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c("D","E","F"))
}

mydf()
> mydf()
a b
1 1 D
2 2 E
3 3 F
```

Is that what you're looking for?

As stated in the comments:

- with larger `data.frame`s (if not for *all*) `data.frame`s, `save`+`load` is a better and more convenient alternative
- the result of `dput(read.csv(...))` can replace `data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c("D","E","F"))` in the example above

Comment: Ok, I see that I should have mentioned that the dataframe in my case is a big one. So I see your point building a function like this. But what I am looking for is a function that leads to a function like yours. Since its is clear how the dataframe looks like, it should be possible for R to think the other way around and build the function that leads to the same output without the need for a saved file etc. Just a function that I could put in a .R source file to other functions that will be saved there. But I think I will use the .RData approach. Thanks anyways.

Comment: in package dev there is the option of lazy load your datasets; eg `iris` without the need of `data(iris)` or any other function call (eg `load` or a custom function). Perhaps this could be comfy if yhis happens to work outside packages but in my humble opinion it's not worth the effort and I'd go for rdas too.